# CSS List formatting menu - menu items shifted down, when image is in the list

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a problem formatting an img inside a nav bar - In the below snippet the navitems line up nicely side by side, until I insert an image inside the .navitem li. Then for some reason I don't understand the next nav items move down somehow.

Can someone explain me why? I know I probably could use flex or table layout to make it work, I just want to understand why it displays like this.

I would have expected, that with height & line-height of the nav = 80px, the image size= 80px that everything would line up vertically centered.

```css
.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  line-height:80px; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.navitem {
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 2em;
  padding: 0; 
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS List Problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav"> 
      <ul>
        <li class="navitem"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"/> </li>
        <li class="navitem">Hello</li>
        <li class="navitem">World</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle; ` should be on the `li` - problem solved

Comment: omg. yeah, maybe I should have gotten that myself. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Paulie_D pointed out in his comment, I put the vertical-align on the parent element instead of the li element itself. well ... yeah ... Didn't someone say there were no stupid questions ;-)

```css
.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  line-height:80px; 
}

.navitem {
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 2em;
  padding: 0; 
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS List Problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav"> 
      <ul>
        <li class="navitem"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"/> </li>
        <li class="navitem">Hello</li>
        <li class="navitem">World</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```